# Add Custom field under the post title

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I've added custom text field to WooCommerce Product:

```
if(function_exists("register_field_group"))
{
    register_field_group(array (
        'id' => 'acf_products',
        'title' => 'Products',
        'fields' => array (
            array (
                'key' => 'field_5b31fba49dfe8',
                'label' => 'Product Long Title',
                'name' => 'product_long_title',
                'type' => 'text',
                'default_value' => '',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter <br/> tag here',
                'prepend' => '',
                'append' => '',
                'formatting' => 'html',
                'maxlength' => '',
            ),
        ),
        'location' => array (
            array (
                array (
                    'param' => 'post_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'product',
                    'order_no' => 0,
                    'group_no' => 0,
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'options' => array (
            'position' => 'normal',
            'layout' => 'no_box',
            'hide_on_screen' => array (
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order' => 0,
    ));
}
```

I would like it to appear under the Product title, as underlined on the picture.

[image]

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `position` param is responsible for that. You can find all params with descriptions [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/register-fields-via-php/#group-settings).

So you'll have to change that part of your code:

```
    'options' => array (
        'position' => 'normal',
        'layout' => 'no_box',
        'hide_on_screen' => array (
        ),
    ),
```

to this:

```
    'options' => array (
        'position' => 'acf_after_title',
        'layout' => 'no_box',
        'hide_on_screen' => array (
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: I did change it to  'position' => 'acf_after_title', but still doesn't appear under the title....

Comment: And where does it appear?

Comment: Between Product short description and Product data

Comment: `after_title` hasn't worked for me in some cases either, so I did just hack it via JS/CSS

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to believe that there is no other solution than that